# Connect with c# to Exchange Server

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I have an Exchange 2010 server. Some users in my company don't use Outlook so they don't get notifications when they receive a new email.

I want to create a C# app that connects as the user to Exchange, finds unread emails, and shows a notification icon.

Does somebody know the best way to do this connection with Exchange?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the EWS-Api (Exchange Web Services). NuGet has it with this name.
With the API you can probably use AutoDiscover to get a connection to your Exchange and then read and write data as required.

Comment: Exchange Web Services are definitely the way to go. Full documentation and samples are available on MSDN, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb204119(v=exchg.140).aspx

Answer (score 0):

We have used Independentsoft [WebDAV .NET for Exchange](http://www.independentsoft.com/webdavex/index.html) to solve this. I costs some money, but it will save you a lot of time!

Comment: Spending money for third party components seems kinda pointless when EWS allows to mimic OWA's behavior for free.

Comment: -1  WebDav support have been deprecated from Exchange Server 2010 (which is what the questions was asked for).  It will not be supported on any newer versions either.